# How to delete entire rows for specific data?

Tags: excel, vba

For below data I want to delete entire rows for which Data1 = Dog.
[image]

I tried two codes:

1st Code: This deletes a single row not all three rows which contain "Dog".

```vb
Sub DeleteRow()
Dim lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each a In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a.Row, 1).Value = "Dog" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a.Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
        **Skip** ("Here I also want to know how to skip for unmatched condition")
    End If
Next a
End Sub
```

2nd Code: I get

> Run time error "424" that is object required

```
Sub DeleteRow()
Dim lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each a In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a.Row, 1).Value = "Dog" Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a.Row, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        lastrow = lastrow - 1
        a = a - 1
    Else
        **Skip** ("Here I also want to know how to skip for unmatched condition")
    End If
Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The classic way would be a numerated for loop backwards.

```
for i = lastrownumber to firstrownumber step -1
   if worksheets(name or index).cells(i, data1 columnnumber).value = "Dog" then
      worksheets(name or index).rows(i).delete
   end if
next i

You need to go upwards, because deleting will shift the rows up and thus you would leave out a row if you go downward.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is working fine at my computer (after some simplifications, as you can see):

```
Sub DeleteRow()
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For Each a In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    If a.Value = "Dog" Then
        a.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next a
End Sub
```